# javascript or css to animate file transfer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I want to show a file transfer...like from a folder to another folder, i have been able to do it using JavaScript but all what i did was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var img;
var animateR;
var animateL;

function init(){
 img = document.getElementById('file');
 img.style.left = '35px'; 
}

function moveRight(){

 img.style.display= 'block'; 
 img.style.left = parseInt(img.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
 animateR = setTimeout(moveRight,30);

 if(parseInt(img.style.left)>600){
   clearTimeout(animateR);
   moveLeft();
  }
}

function moveLeft(){

  img.style.left = parseInt(img.style.left) - 10 + 'px';
  animateL = setTimeout(moveLeft,30); 

   if(parseInt(img.style.left)<38){
     clearTimeout(animateL);
     moveRight();
     }
 }

 window.onload =init;
 </script>
```

this work for me but i wish to show the file rotating whilst moving from the right folder to the left folder and back to the riight fold while the file is uploading.

also i am think if the best way to go around this will be a gif?

**i want an effect like flying files**

Comment: Can you show me the output?

Comment: the code above, all it does right now is (1) show a hidden file (2)animates the file to move to the file (3) when it has moved up to 600px to the right then i starts moving back to the left also when it gets to a width of like 38px it goes back to the right...and the loop continues. @PraJen

Comment: http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/ just sayn'

Comment: I really think that a gif animation would be the best, coding this is kind of an overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate images in css like this :

```
#rot{
    animation: anime1 2s;
    -webkit-animation: anime1 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes anime1 {
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);/*Chrome & Opera*/
        transform: rotate(360deg); /* The best browser (i mean firefox) */
    }
}


@-webkit-keyframes anime1 {
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Then just use js to display or hide animated image

Comment: Thanks @Black-Hole but im a little bit confuse here about #rot and anime1 can you be nice to help me put it up on fiddle?

Comment: @user2666633 #rot is the id of img tags for example : <img id="rot" src=..>    and to understand anime1 take a look here :
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I have read your code correctly, you are making the file bounce back and forth between your right and left bounds. You could use the CSS3 transform property to rotate the files as they are moving back and forth as such.

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
```

However, you are still just moving your image file in 10 pixel increments, which probably looks choppy. A better solution would be to use CSS keyframe animations.